# Freebase topic assignment for a fresh video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, freebase

I know Youtube is doing semantic annotation using Freebase API. When does a new video get assigned a freebase topic? How many hours does it take? Is there any API for setting a trigger when these annotations are ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations are produced in the order of minutes after upload but they show up in API calls around 2 to 4 hours later.